# Linq-To-Sql SP won't map to class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a class in my Linq-To-Sql model and am trying to map a Stored Procedure to it.  Whatever I try I get the message:

```
one or more selected database objects return a schema that does not match
```

The schema definitely does match, I have even resorted to just doing a auto generated 'select top 100 rows' in SSMS and putting this in the SP, nothing else, and I still get this message.

Is there anything else I should be looking at?

My table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NULL,
    [BookingTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [LinkedBookingID] [int] NULL,
    [DateCreated] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [DateUpdated] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [BookingDateTime] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [BookingStatusID] [int] NULL,
    [ConfirmationRequired] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Confirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InProgress] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ServiceID] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [Duration] [int] NULL,
    [ProcessingDuration] [int] NULL,
    [IsPartOfCourse] [bit] NULL,
    [CancellationReason] [int] NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
    [IsLinked] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Booking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE booking_test


AS
BEGIN


SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[ClientID]
      ,[BookingTypeID]
      ,[LinkedBookingID]
      ,[DateCreated]
      ,[DateUpdated]
      ,[BookingDateTime]
      ,[BookingStatusID]
      ,[ConfirmationRequired]
      ,[Confirmed]
      ,[InProgress]
      ,[ServiceID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[Duration]
      ,[ProcessingDuration]
      ,[IsPartOfCourse]
      ,[CancellationReason]
      ,[Timestamp]

  FROM [Booking]

END
GO
```

Comment: Show some SP code/schema/objects please? Also could there be any inconsistencies between your linq2sql class and the tables from the sp?

Comment: @Jimmy, updated with table structure

Comment: Have you tried doing a `select *` instead of cherry picking columns?

Comment: You're not returning the `IsLinked BIT` column from the stored proc - maybe that causes the mismatch.... or did you by any chance change the database schema after having created your Linq-to-SQL model?? You might need to update that model

Comment: Something is missing, share a screen shot of your linq datamodel and maybe your class code if you have any aside from what is gen'd by the designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[IsLinked]` to the queried columns in your stored procedure and it should work. (I just tested with your table, etc, and adding `[IsLinked]` to the stored procedure allowed me to drop the stored procedure onto the table in the designer without an error.)

I know that if you're using a stored procedure to query objects which *are not* LINQ to SQL entities (but you're using LINQ to SQL to auto-populate the objects), you can skip columns like you did with `[IsLinked]`.  But if you're querying objects that *are* LINQ to SQL entities, you have to query all the columns.  I think that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have also gone through this issue.

The default method returns a generic type called `ISingleResult`. This type is
defined in the `System.Data.Linq namespace` and enables you to represent the results of a mapped function that has a single return sequence.

This can be helpful when you build custom queries that do not return all the fields, but table entity is already defined in our Designer and that is what we would like to work with.

To change the method to return the table entity, you have to remove the stored procedure from the Methods pane of the **ORM Designer**. Drag the stored procedure from the Server Explorer onto the table instead of the Methods pane. The procedure will appear in the Methods pane again but now look at the code that was
generated. The select method now returns ISingleResult 
entities, and the tableselectall class was removed:

You need to check if table fields and fields you are selecting in storedprocedure is maching ( No filed is missing)
I have added missing field within stored procedure and error resolved.